# Slim -- Add target in link_to

Tags: html, slim-lang

The origin slim code is:

```
= link_to page.info_page_link do
  .price == "Gold: <br>#{page.entry_fee}"
  .price.right == "Fee:<br>#{page.popular_price}"
  .calendar == "Time:<br>#{page.popular_period}"
  .clock == "Process:<br>#{page.hours}"
```

Now, I must add a `target="_blank"` to this link, I try:

```
= link_to target: '_blank', page.info_page_link do
  .price == "Gold: <br>#{page.entry_fee}"
  .price.right == "Fee:<br>#{page.popular_price}"
  .calendar == "Time:<br>#{page.popular_period}"
  .clock == "Process:<br>#{page.hours}"
```

But the browser says "syntax error".

Comment: Is your question about slim template engine for ruby? If so, please consider removng `slim` tag and adding `slim-lang` tag.

Comment: @Nima Yeah, I do it, now, tell me answer!

Comment: Now wait for ruby guys to hopefully show up and help you :)

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, it is params order question.

Just move target hash to next location:

```
= link_to page.info_page_link, target: '_blank' do
  .price == "Gold: <br>#{page.entry_fee}"
  .price.right == "Fee:<br>#{page.popular_price}"
  .calendar == "Time:<br>#{page.popular_period}"
  .clock == "Process:<br>#{page.hours}"
```

Then it works! This is the API doc:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html